# Concurrent use of OSEK_TP.DLL

Tags: capl, canoe

I have a CANoe simulateur with a main node which uses OSEK_TP.DLL

I'd like to create another node (to be reusable easily) with different usefull "on keyboard 'x'" macros to send CANext messages, alos with OSEK_TP.DLL

Can I have different nodes using OSEK_TP.DLL ? Does everyone handles its own context : for example, can I declare in each "on start" call a different OSEKTL_SetRxId value ?

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Basically a simulation node is the simulation of an ECU. So yeah, each node can reference and use the OSEK_TP.DLL. Each node is simulated with a different CAPL file. So yeah, they can have different "on start" callbacks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I was asking this question because I suspected my new node to have an influence on another one.